# Tortoise SVN include part of project in other project

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a Tortoise SVN repository that has 3 projects in it:

```
DAL
Services
Controller
```

These 3 projects combined are call `MainProject`

I want to be able to extract the `DAL` only from the repository `MainProject`, and then include it in other repositories going forward.

Is this possible, and if so how can I do it?

This would mean that if I then included the `DAL` in `MainProject2`, I could simply update the `DAL` and any changes made in `DAL` in `MainProject` would move to `MainProject2` via the update command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding DAL as external project.

Right click on you current project, let's call it `ProjectA`, select `ToroiseSVN/Properties/New` and choose `External`. Enter the SVN path to DAL.

Then you need to do 2 things:
1. Commit - so your new `external` property will be saved to the repository.
2. Update - this will bring DAL to ProjectA as external.

If you update DAL and commit it, and then `update` ProjectA, it will pull the updated DAL.

But there is a catch here.
If want to go back to previous versions of ProjectA, SVN will still give it to you with the most updated DAL version, which in most cases will not be what you want.

Hence the preferred way is not to link to the HEAD revision of DAL, but rather to a specific revision. This way you revisions of ProjectA are linked with a specific revision of DAL. Whenever you update DAL, you can update you external to point to the newer DAL revision, the commit and update ProjectA.